# Number of days between two dates in Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

How do I find the difference in Days between two [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances?
With ‘difference in days’ I mean if start is on Monday and end is on Tuesday I expect a return value of 1 regardless of the hour/minute/seconds of the start and end dates.

`Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays()` gives me 0 if start is in the evening and end in the morning.

I'm also having the same issue with other date fields so I was hoping there would be a generic way to 'ignore' the fields of lesser significance.

In other words, the months between Feb and 4 March would also be 1, as would the hours between 14:45 and 15:12 be. However the hour difference between 14:01 and 14:55 would be 0.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

Annoyingly, the withTimeAtStartOfDay answer is wrong, but only occasionally. You want:

```
Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays()
```

It turns out that "midnight/start of day" sometimes means 1am (daylight savings happen this way in some places), which Days.daysBetween doesn't handle properly.

```
// 5am on the 20th to 1pm on the 21st, October 2013, Brazil
DateTimeZone BRAZIL = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo");
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 10, 20, 5, 0, 0, BRAZIL);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 10, 21, 13, 0, 0, BRAZIL);
System.out.println(daysBetween(start.withTimeAtStartOfDay(),
                               end.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays());
// prints 0
System.out.println(daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(),
                               end.toLocalDate()).getDays());
// prints 1
```

Going via a `LocalDate` sidesteps the whole issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example case with specific data where you think [`Days.daysBetween`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-) is incorrect?

Comment: When you say to use `Instant`, you're not just talking about `start.toInstant()`, are you?

Comment: @PatrickM Yes, I was. On reflection, it's not clear exactly what constraints this is intended to impose, so I'll remove that last sentence. Thanks!

Comment: @chrispy daysBetween doc says it returns number of **WHOLE** days. In my case 2 days and 1 hour should return me 3 days. In your example it returns 2 days. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @SujitJoshi I'm afraid I don't understand your question. I suggest posting a full Stack Overflow question and pasting a link here for me :)

Comment: Beware of dates overlapping with a new year! Days between 31 dec 2016 and 5 jan 2017 gives -361 days.

Comment: @Sylphe No, it doesn't, I just checked. I suspect you typo'd 2017.

Answer (score 195):

## `Days` Class

Using the [`Days`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) class with the [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) method should work:

```
Days.daysBetween(start.withTimeAtStartOfDay() , end.withTimeAtStartOfDay() ).getDays()
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to achieve the behavior of android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString() with joda and this was really useful.

Comment: Sir, with reference to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17665921/1031945) the method `toDateMidnight()` from the type DateTime is deprecated.

Comment: You should now use .withTimeAtStartOfDay() instead of .toDateMidnight()

Comment: what if the `end` is before the `start`, does it returns negative days?

Comment: @akhyar: why don't you try it?

Comment: How do I change the internal behavior of this method to be inclusive of all the dates? For instance, if the dates are the same, the number of days should be 1. Ignoring the time fields

Answer (score 91):

you can use [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html):

```
Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(start), new LocalDate(end)).getDays()
```

Comment: Sir, with reference to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17665921/1031945) the method `toDateMidnight()` from the type DateTime is deprecated.

Comment: Why use `new LocalDate(date)` over `date.toLocalDate()` ?

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
    earlier.toLocalDate(), 
    later.toLocalDate() 
)
```

…or…

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( 
    earlier.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS )  , 
    later.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) 
)
```

## java.time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The equivalent of Joda-Time `DateTime` is `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Apparently you want to count the days by dates, meaning you want to ignore the time of day. For example, starting a minute before midnight and ending a minute after midnight should result in a single day. For this behavior, extract a `LocalDate` from your `ZonedDateTime`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate localDateStart = zdtStart.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate localDateStop = zdtStop.toLocalDate() ;
```

Use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum to calculate elapsed days or other units.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( localDateStart , localDateStop ) ;
```

## Truncate

As for you asking about a more general way to do this counting where you are interested the delta of hours as hour-of-the-clock rather than complete hours as spans-of-time of sixty minutes, use the `truncatedTo` method.

Here is your example of 14:45 to 15:12 on same day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); 
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017 , 1 , 17 , 14 , 45 , 0 , 0 , z );
ZonedDateTime stop = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017 , 1 , 17 , 15 , 12 , 0 , 0 , z );

long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between( start.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) , stop.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) );
```

> 1

**This does not work for days.** Use toLocalDate() in this case.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Your TL;DR for days using truncate falls prey to the bug detailed in the accepted answer, namely it is off-by-one when start-of-day is at 1am. I have updated it to use the correct answer you gave further down, using toLocalDate.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer builds two `LocalDate` objects, which are quite expensive if you are reading lot of data.
I use this:

```
  public static int getDaysBetween(DateTime earlier, DateTime later)
  {
    return (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(later.getMillis()- earlier.getMillis());
  }
```

By calling `getMillis()` you use already existing variables.
`MILLISECONDS.toDays()` then, uses a simple arithmetic calculation, does not create any object.

Comment: This Answer works only if your definition of ‘days’ is exactly 24-hours long without regard for time zones and dates. If so, use this approach. If not, look to the other answers that address time zones.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you are right, still, i would go for a solution based on arithmetic calculation rather then building expensive objects for each method call, there are many flavours out there for such calculations, if you are reading an input from a web page, might be ok, but if you are processing a log file with hundreds of thousands of lines this just makes it very slow

Comment: Java will optimize away the object allocation if your loop is hot. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time.Period`

Use the [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class to [count days](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getDays--).

Since Java 8 calculating the difference is more intuitive using `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` to represent the two dates

```
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 28);

    Period period = Period.between( inputDate, now);
    int diff = period.getDays();
    System.out.println("diff = " + diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

**(KOTLIN) For Difference between a constant date and current date (Joda)**

You can use `Days.daysBetween(jodaDate1,jodaDate2)`

Here is an example:

```
        val dateTime: DateTime = DateTime.parse("14/09/2020",
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        val currentDate = DateTime.now()
        //To calculate the days in between
        val dayCount = Days.daysBetween(dateTime,currentDate).days
        //Set Value to TextView 
        binding.daysCount.text = dayCount.toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime  dt  = new DateTime(laterDate);        

DateTime newDate = dt.minus( new  DateTime ( previousDate ).getMillis());

System.out.println("No of days : " + newDate.getDayOfYear() - 1 );
```

Answer (score -12):

```
public static int getDifferenceIndays(long timestamp1, long timestamp2) {
    final int SECONDS = 60;
    final int MINUTES = 60;
    final int HOURS = 24;
    final int MILLIES = 1000;
    long temp;
    if (timestamp1 < timestamp2) {
        temp = timestamp1;
        timestamp1 = timestamp2;
        timestamp2 = temp;
    }
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    endDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp1);
    startDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp2);
    if ((timestamp1 - timestamp2) < 1 * HOURS * MINUTES * SECONDS * MILLIES) {
        int day1 = endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int day2 = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day1 == day2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int diffDays = 0;
    startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, diffDays);
    while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        diffDays++;
    }
    return diffDays;
}
```

Comment: the question is specifically looking for joda-time.