# How to subtract two joda datetimes?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I know this isn't "the way it's supposed to work", but still: If you have two DateTime objects, what's a good way to subtract them? Convert them to Date objects?

```
DateTime start = new DateTime();
System.out.println(start + " - doing some stuff");

// do stuff

DateTime end = new DateTime();
Period diff = // end - start ???
System.out.println(end + " - doing some stuff took diff seconds");
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jodatime#) should help you.

Comment: @karmanaut - thanks, closing as dup.

Comment: @karmanaut That question doesn't really cover the same ground. It counts the number of *days* between two instants, not a general way to go from a start and end date to a period.

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: @ParkashKumar Good catch, an `Interval` is probably better for this use.

Comment: @millimoose, maybe OP wouldn't use .getDays() method to get days between two days. But you are right. [Here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff) is the official document for this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Period has [a constructor that takes two `ReadableInstant` instances](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29):

```
Period diff = new Period(start, end);
```

(`ReadableInstant` is an interface implemented by `DateTime`, as well as other classes.)

Answer (score 22):

From your example you seem to want the difference in seconds so [this should help](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Seconds.html#secondsBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) :

```
Seconds diff = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end);
```

Answer (score 7):

Does this help? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html
It shows the below example

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// period of 1 year and 7 days
Period period = new Period(start, end);

// calc will equal end
DateTime calc = start.plus(period);

// able to calculate whole days between two dates easily
Days days = Days.daysBetween(start, end);
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends in which precision you want to get. You should check the `org.joda.time` package and check for the Helper classes such as `Hours`, `Days`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a `Period` using [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) constructor which takes two `DateTime` objects.