# Number of days between two dates (excluding these two dates)

Tags: java, android

I searched for this is SO there are so many post asking this question but all the answers is `difference In Milliseconds / (24* 1000 * 60 * 60)` that gives the number of 24 Hrs between two dates .
but i need the number of days between 2 dates.

I.e. if `date1` is `09/09/13 09:00` and `date2` is `10/09/13 22:00` I need the difference as `0` and not `1` because `date1` and `date2` are consecutive days (even if there is more than 24 hour gap between them).

**Note**: I know the removing the time part and using the  `difference In Milliseconds / (24* 1000 * 60 * 60)` method. I am looking for a better solution.

**update**: the app is first used on `09/09/13 09:00` its a Wednesday then the app was used on  10/09/13 22:00` its Thursday. now the user has used the app both Wednesday and Thursday even though there is more than 24 hour gap. now if i calculate the number of 24 hours between the 2 dates it gives one. as there is a day gap between 2 dates. i need it to give zero as the user used it Wednesday and Thursday there is **NO DAY BETWEEN WEDNESDAY AND THURSDAY**. 
hope you understood my question. if you still didn't just leave it, i tried by best explaining.

Comment: Difference between `09/09/13 09:00` and `10/09/13 22:00` is `1d:13h` so why result should be 0 days?

Comment: because 09/09/13 09:00 and 10/09/13 22:00 are consecutive days. there is more than 24 hour gap but they are consecutive days. so it should return 0

Comment: `09/09/13` to `10/09/13` should return 0 in your algorithm. What about `09/09/13` to `11/09/13`? It should be 1 or 2?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that this does not really make any sense?
Tomorrow is tomorrow and not today... and what about a difference of more than 48h? Is it 1 day or 2 days?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih I have the same question.

Comment: @Mauren 09/09/13 to 11/09/13 returns 1 because there is one day between these 2 dates.

Comment: Then just substract one day in milliseconds from the difference...

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih this is what I was going to say hahaha

Comment: @billgates then you want the number of days placed **in between** the two dates. Just calculate the difference of days between two dates and subtract 1.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih if i do so then the difference between `09/09/13 09:00` and '10/09/13 08:00' will be -1(negative one).

Comment: So you want the difference between 2 dates exclusive of both dates? i.e. the number of days inbetween, but not including the 2 dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(startDate);

while(calendar.getTime().before(endDate))
 {
    noOfDays++;
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
 }
```

Where startDate and endDate are instances of the [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) class.

Note: You need to initialize the date objects so that they have the same time but only differ in their dates. Setting them both to 12 AM should do the trick:

```
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: you need to add a `date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1)` in your loop

Comment: `before()` returns true only if the difference between dates is in days?

Comment: @billgates no. We need to initialize dates properly. Setting them both to the same time and letting them differ only in their dates should ensure that this works properly.

Comment: so removing the time part is the only solution?

Comment: @billgates you can set them to any time as long as they're both the same. If you need the original time, then just use temp copies for calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String dateStart = "09/09/13 09:00";
        String dateStop = "10/09/13 22:00";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        Date date1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        Date date2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            // calculate difference in milliseconds
        long diff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) - 86400000;
        diff = (diff <= 0 ? 0 : diff);

        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff));
    }

}
```

This will give the difference between 2 dates. And subtract a day (if its negative, it sets the difference to 0 day). This will work as long as dateStop is greater than dateStart, otherwise it will just print 0;

Comment: I think converting time difference into days will get the number of 24 hours.

Comment: @billgates I'm a little confused trying to understand your logic, because 24h is actually one day, so the number of 24h between two dates is obviously the number of days.

Comment: @billgates Does this work for you now? It only tells you the number of dates inbetween, 9~10th = 0 days inbetween. 9~11th = 1 day inbetween.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have avoided using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for ages, but this past week I got round to using it for exactly this issue. And it was well worth it!

It is very easy to introduce some strange date handling bugs when dealing with plain Java - for example what happens when daylight savings time changes. Joda Time builds all these exceptions in already.

Check related question here:

- [Number of days between two dates in Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time)

---

**Update**

As of Java 8, the time & date functionality has been improved, and the Joda Time team suggests using that instead of their library. Here's what they say on the landing page:

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to
>   java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
>   project.

[Thanks to Basil Bourque for the comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317024/number-of-days-between-two-dates-excluding-these-two-dates/19317680?noredirect=1#comment85660603_19317680)

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick: if `date1` is before `date2` you can set hour in `date1` to `1` and in `date2` to `0`. This way hour part in entire time difference will never be greater than 24h, so will not affect calculations so only days/months/years will matter.

Here is code example

```
public static long daysBetween(Date date1, Date date2) {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(date1);

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(date2);
    if (date1.before(date2)) {
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    } else {
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    }

    return (c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis())
            / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

//DEMO
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");
    Date date1 = df.parse("09/09/13 09:00");
    Date date2 = df.parse("11/09/13 22:00");

    System.out.println(daysBetween(date1, date2));
}
```

Output: `1`

---

For dates `11/09/13 09:00` `09/09/13 22:00` result will be `-1` since `date1` is after `date2`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    earlierInstant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).toLocalDate() ,
    Instant.now().atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).toLocalDate()
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

If you want to calculate the number of elapsed days as the number of calendar dates rather than the number of 24-hour chunks of time, use a date-only class rather than a date-time class.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Generally best to think, work, log, serialize, and exchange values in UTC. For that, use `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant earlier = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant later = Instant.now() ;
```

Serialize to text in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `Instant::toString` and `Instant::parse`.

To get your elapsed dates, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = earlier.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = later.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only values.

```
LocalDate ldEarlier = zdtEarlier.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate ldLater = zdtLater.toLocalDate() ;
```

Now we can get the elapsed days between the dates.

```
long daysElapsed = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ldEarlier , ldLater ) ;
```

This calculation is done per the *Half-Open* approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So, for example, a month starts with the first day of the month and runs up to, but does not include, the first day of the *following* month. Using this approach consistently throughout your business logic, database queries, and so on will make your codebase less error-prone and easier to read/debug/maintain.

I understand you want to use a fully-Open approach where both beginning and ending is exclusive. I strongly suggest you reconsider that position. But if you insist, simply subtract `1` from our calculation above.

```
long daysElapsedFullyOpen = ( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ldEarlier , ldLater ) - 1 ) ;  // Subtract 1 to get a fully-Open answer. NOT recommended.
```

By the way, you may want to consider the `Period` class in your work. Similarly, you may find useful the `LocalDateRange` class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).