# Days difference in dates in java giving wrong output

Tags: java, date

Hi i am trying to calculate difference of two dates in days. The dates are 14 of this month and today. It should be 2. But o/p is 0 always.
Code:

```
    long today = (new java.util.Date().getTime());
    long difference =(long) (today - 1394809789186.0);
    long daysdifference = difference/(24*3600*1000);
    System.out.println(daysdifference);
```

o/p:
0.

whats wrong?

Now i did another trick and it gives perfect answer dont know whats wrong with above code...

```
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"); 
    long firstdateseconds = df.parse("14.03.2014").getTime();
    long today = df.parse("16.03.2014").getTime();
    long difference = (today-firstdateseconds);
    long days = (long)(difference/(24*3600*1000));
    System.out.println(days);
```

o/p : 2 // now correct bingo!

Guys whats happening?

Comment: You should try printing out intermediate values to see what's going on.  Also, what is the magic number `1394809789186.0`?

Comment: @oli: it's a millisecond timestamp that corresponds to Mar 14th.

Comment: @MarcB: Yeah, I assumed that ;)  But I'm wondering why the OP has that hardcoded, rather than simply explicitly constructing it as such.

Comment: Probably caused by dividing `difference` by an `int`.

Comment: Looks fine here: http://ideone.com/S6ZCpa.

Comment: If you used the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API, you would never have to worry about such calculations.

Comment: Regarding your edit; did you think to print out the values of `firstdateseconds` and `today`, and see how they correspond to your magic hard-coded number?

Comment: I dont know why people just downvote instead of directly showing the mistakes.

Comment: @ Tiny, I beleive in Java se7 developers and my brain and people here helping others, more than the joda..whatever API.

Comment: @Deepsthecoder: the code print 2 in both conditions

Comment: I got 2 on the first block too

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3802949/642706) for a simple one-liner using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library: `Days.daysBetween(start.withTimeAtStartOfDay() , end.withTimeAtStartOfDay() ).getDays()`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following simple code to accomplish what you want:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class datediff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date d1 = new Date();
        Date d2 = new Date(2014 - 1900, 2, 14);
        long d1_millis = d1.getTime();
        long d2_millis = d2.getTime();
        long diffMillis = d1_millis - d2_millis;
        long diffDays = diffMillis / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Difference in days: " + diffDays);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Difference in days: 2

---

Also note that the magic number that you are using while calculating the difference is incorrect.

**The actual value to subtract is : 1394735400000**

That is the most dangerous disadvantage of using magic numbers.

Hope that clarifies things for you.

Comment: Please check the ranges of the inputs to the `Date` constructor in the Javadoc...

Comment: I have simplified the code and also given the output.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a combined `TimeZone` and "Time (hours/minutes/seconds)" issue?

**Case I**

Different timezones and different day times:

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Calendar march14 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
    march14.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 14, 23, 59, 0);

    final Calendar march16 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
    march16.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 16, 0, 0, 0);

    final long diffInMs = march16.getTimeInMillis() - march14.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("diff = " + diffInMs / (24 * 3600 * 1000)+" day(s)");

}
```

This prints:

> diff = 0 day(s)

**Case II**

However, adjusting the time zone:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Calendar march14 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
    march14.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 14, 23, 59, 0);

    final Calendar march16 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii")); // <- CHANGE!
    march16.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 16, 0, 0, 0);

    final long diffInMs = march16.getTimeInMillis() - march14.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("diff = " + diffInMs / (24 * 3600 * 1000)+" day(s)");

}
```

This prints:

> diff = 1 day(s)

**Case III**

And adjusting the time (hours/minutes/seconds):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Calendar march14 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
    march14.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 14, 0, 0, 0);  // <- CHANGE!

    final Calendar march16 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
    march16.set(2014, Calendar.MARCH, 16, 0, 0, 0);

    final long diffInMs = march16.getTimeInMillis() - march14.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println("diff = " + diffInMs / (24 * 3600 * 1000)+" day(s)");

}
```

This prints:

> diff = 2 day(s)

**Conclusions**

My two advices:

- Don't use magic numbers, set all parts of your date/calendar objects that are relevant
- Always set the `TimeZone` when working with date/time

**Additional note to SimpleDateFormat**

By the way: In `SimpleDateFormat` `m` is for minutes, `M` for month in year, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. It was pure random that the result of your calculations was `2`.

Answer (score -1):

Use double you are crossing a truncation issue

Comment: Use `double` for what?

Comment: Now did this:
        long today = (new java.util.Date().getTime());
        double difference =(double) (today - 1394809789186.0);
        double daysdifference = difference/(24*3600*1000);
o/p : 0.008885162037037037

Comment: When i use long it says number too long in netbeans.. so used double

Comment: Because there is a division and it truncates to 0 if one day is not elapsed.