# Using the Java CLASS Day to find number of days since specific date e.g. birthday?

Tags: java, class, datetime, import, datepicker

The Day class knows about the intricacies of our
calendar, such as the fact that January has 31 days and
February has 28 or sometimes 29.

I am trying to implement this public class into my program however I am unable to, I am making a program that calculates how many **days** a person has been alive for

This is the code given within the textbook:

```
public class DaysAlivePrinter 
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Day jamesGoslingsBirthday = new Day(1955, 5, 19);
       Day today = new Day();
       System.out.print("Today: ");
       System.out.println(today.toString());
       int daysAlive = today.daysFrom(jamesGoslingsBirthday);
       System.out.print("Days alive: ");
       System.out.println(daysAlive);
  }
}
```

I mostly understand the JavaDoc - http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Day.html - but nowhere does it say how to import the functionality of the Day class into your program. What is the process to do this?

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend using either `java.time` if you're using Java 8, or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) for this, rather than part of a random charting API.

Comment: You might want to use `joda time` and the answer from this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Comment: Are you asking how to use an `import` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the java time api (Java 8):

```
LocalDate jamesGoslingsBirthday = LocalDate.of(1955, 5, 19);
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("Today: " + today);
int daysAlive = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(jamesGoslingsBirthday, today);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I was able to obtain solution like I wanted!

Comment: @CJCarter If you found a solution you can post it as an answer.