# Android Datepicker calculate days to birthday

Tags: android, datepicker

when I try to calculate the days for birthday
always gives me the wrong number of days

Can you help me what is wrong?

```
    Calendar call1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar call2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day2 = call2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month2 = call2.get(Calendar.MONTH );
    int year2 = call2.get(Calendar.YEAR);


    if (month2 > month  ) {

    }

    else if (month == month2 ){

        if(year2 < day ){

        }
    }call1.set(day2, month , day);
    long millis = call2.getTimeInMillis()
            - call1.getTimeInMillis();
            long days = millis / 86400000L;

     Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "The number of days until your birthday"
             + days, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
     text2.setText(""+ days);
     text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
```

---

This is the first part of the code:

```
   SharedPreferences dp2 = this.getSharedPreferences("dp", 0);

    int day = dp2.getInt("day", 0);
    int month = dp2.getInt("month", 0) + 1;
    int year = dp2.getInt("year", 0);

    text1.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

Comment: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android. Use Joda time.  Date between a range http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method to find the difference between two dates.

```
/**
 * Get a diff between two dates
 * @param date1 the oldest date
 * @param date2 the newest date
 * @param timeUnit the unit in which you want the diff
 * @return the diff value, in the provided unit
 */
public static long getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

And then can you call:

```
getDateDiff(date1,date2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

to get the diff of the 2 dates in minutes unit.

`TimeUnit` is `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`, a standard Java enum going from nanos to days.