# Time between Dates using LocalDate and Period

Tags: java

If I do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.MARCH, 12);
    LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 13);
    System.out.println(d1.until(d2).getDays());
    // Prints 11
    LocalDate d3 = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 25);
    // Prints 23.
```

Both of which are incorrect. The second output makes sense as there is 1 month and 23 days between them.

How do I get the total number of days between?

I would want the first output to be 32 Days and the second to be 44 days (the total number of days between
the two dates).

What am I doing wrong? I don't see a `totalDays()` method.

Comment: Hint: `13-12=1`, `25-12=13`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not use a period (which has year and month components) if you are only interested in days. One solution to your question is:

```
System.out.println(DAYS.between(d1, d2)); //32
```

or alternatively:

```
System.out.println(d1.until(d2, DAYS)); //32
```

Note: I'm using `import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;`

Comment: Or `d1.until(d2, ChronoUnit.DAYS)`.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed.

I remember doing it in C++ where you make a period and then there is a function to get total number of days in that period, thought it worked the same in Java.

Thank you!

Comment: @Marcin A Period does not have a notion of a start or end date - so you can't convert 1 month 1 day into total days (would it be 29? 30? 31? 32?).

Comment: You're right.

Then I must be getting mixed up with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you want to do with dates and possible you don't need it but I really recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time) is how to get number of days between two dates. 

In Java 8 we finally have good Dates library but if you don't use Java 8 then you have to get Joda Time