# How to calculate number of days between two datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, android-datepicker

When user select `date` between from and to `date`. how to `calculate` number of night in 3rd `Edittext` in android?
Following my code for `datepicker`

```
3 edittext box
```

**1 From Date
2 To Date
3 Number of night = ?**

```
 CheckInDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckInDate);

        CheckOutDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckOutDate);





        CheckInDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v == CheckInDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);


                    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    if(cal.before(c)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select valid date please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
                                    date.delete(0, date.length());
                                    date.append((dayOfMonth<10?"0":"")).append(dayOfMonth)
                                            .append("/").append((monthOfYear + 1) < 10 ? "0" : "")
                                            .append((monthOfYear+1)).append("/").append(year);
                                    CheckInDate.setText(date.toString());
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dpd.show();
                }

            }

        });

        CheckOutDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v == CheckOutDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);


                    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    if(cal.before(c)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select valid date please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
                                    date.delete(0, date.length());
                                    date.append((dayOfMonth<10?"0":"")).append(dayOfMonth)
                                            .append("/").append((monthOfYear + 1) < 10 ? "0" : "")
                                            .append((monthOfYear+1)).append("/").append(year);
                                    CheckOutDate.setText(date.toString());
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dpd.show();                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: You can use Joda Time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Date checkInTime, checkOutTime;
 private void checkDiff() {
    long duration = checkOutTime.getTime() - checkInTime.getTime();

    long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
    long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
    long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
    //Now Code as per requirement
}


        CheckInDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckInDate);
        CheckOutDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckOutDate);

        CheckInDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v == CheckInDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);

                    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    if (cal.before(c)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select valid date please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    checkInTime = cal.getTime();
                                    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
                                    date.delete(0, date.length());
                                    date.append((dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" : "")).append(dayOfMonth)
                                            .append("/").append((monthOfYear + 1) < 10 ? "0" : "")
                                            .append((monthOfYear + 1)).append("/").append(year);
                                    CheckInDate.setText(date.toString());
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dpd.show();
                }

            }

        });

        CheckOutDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v == CheckOutDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                    checkOutTime = c.getTime();

                    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                    if (cal.before(c)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select valid date please.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
                                    date.delete(0, date.length());
                                    date.append((dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" : "")).append(dayOfMonth)
                                            .append("/").append((monthOfYear + 1) < 10 ? "0" : "")
                                            .append((monthOfYear + 1)).append("/").append(year);
                                    CheckOutDate.setText(date.toString());
                                    checkOutTime = cal.getTime();
                                    checkDiff();
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dpd.show();
                }

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: In your case make two public refrecesh of Date (let say checkInDate and checkOutDate) in onDateSet get the date from calender and assign to respective reference. In onDateSet of second(i.e. checkout) you can calculate difference between both dates.

Comment: I'm beginner bro :(