# Android get day count between two day return different value for android below and above 6.0

Tags: java, android, date

I had try to get day different between two specific date using below code but the same date passed in return a different value for android below and above android 6.0

here is my function to get the day count:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar base_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
baseDate = chineseDateFormat.parse("1900-1-3");
        base_cal.setTime(baseDate);
int offset = (int) ((cal.getTimeInMillis() - base_cal.getTimeInMillis()) / 86400000L);
```

I realized that the **cal.getTimeInMillis()** can return the same value for different os version but **base_cal.getTimeInMillis()** will return different value for different android os version and it always different by one day

Comment: If you cannot find a reasonable answer, try working with "unix epoch". I've used this and works. Additionally, if you're not aware about that, 2016 is a leap year - maybe this is acting on the results you're getting. Best.

Comment: Are you sure your "chineseDateFormat" object is defined correctly?

Comment: yes the chineseDateFormat object is defined correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "baseDate" is the result of parsing a date string. I don't read Chinese, so I can't tell what the format is, but I suspect that the problem is that your parsed date has a different time of day from the date returned by getTimeInMillis(), and the result is a rounding error.

I further suspect that what you expect is the difference between the two dates, without respect to time of day.

The easiest way to do this correctly and repeatably is to use the Joda date library. There's a port specifically for Android at  https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

You can see an example at [Number of days between two dates in Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time)

Comment: Actually, Joda-Time has been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).