# group date ranges into buckets

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have a problem where I have a date range and I want to split the date range into chunks (quantity provided by user).  Each chunk must be a continuous range of whole months.  The longest chunk must be equal to or one month longer than the shortest.

Date ranges are whole months, as well:

- start dates always are the first of the month
- end dates will always be the last day of the month.

You can assume that The input range will be large enough that each chunk can have at least one whole month.

For example, consider the trivial case of a date range 1/1/2000 through 8/31/2000, 8 chunks requested.  Then each chunk would get a full month.

An easier way to think of this problem is as follows
Consider a list of numbers from 1-15
and we want to split them into 8 chunks
possible combinations are

```
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) -> satisfies only one constraints of using up all the chunks
(1,9),(2,10), (3,11), (4,12), (5,13), (6,14), (7,15), (8) ---> satisfies only 1 constraint of minimizing the difference between maximum number and minimum numbers in a chunk.

(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) (9,10), (11,12) (13,14), 15  ---> correct
```

I have considered joda time as the date library.

This is not a homework problem.  I am trying to parallelize a query which takes date ranges as an input.  The chunks are meant to be cores, and I want to run the query for subsequent date ranges across a core.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like a homework problem... Please ask a specific question. [Look here on how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what can I try ? I  have pared down the problem to where I am stuck. which is the constraint of having the difference minimized.
I dont think the question deserves a down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a hard problem.  There's a simple construction to do the job.  First of all, note that you don't care about days, merely full months.

- Compute the number of months in the range.  Forget the days, just use
  month and year.  Call those inputs `m1/d1/y1` (start) and `m2/d2/y2` (end).  `m_range = 12*(y2-y1) + m2-m1 + 1`.
- Call the input chunk count `chunk`.  If `m_range < chunk`, you have invalid input.
- The minimum chunk size is `min_size = floor(m_range/chunk)` (truncated division).  The max size is one more.
- If the division isn't even, then you'll have some leftover months to allocate.  Compute this extra as `extra = m_range mod chunk`.

With these parameters, the allocation is simple: the first `extra` chunks get an extra month each, and will be of size `min_size+1`.  The remaining `chunk-extra` chunks get `min_size` months each.

For instance, let's take a range 1/1/2017 - 5/31/2018, and 4 chunks.

```
m_range = 12*(2018-2017) + (5-1) + 1 = 12 + 4 + 1 = 17
min_size = floor(m_range/chunk) = floor(17/4) = 4
extra = m_range mod chunk = 1
```

So, you give the first chunk 5 months; the other 3 chunks get 4 months each.

The individual date manipulations are left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: yes. i think this is the right way and it struck me that i can do the pre processing and then assign the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Given a date range calculate how many days are in that range. I'm not familiar with joda data library, maybe it can do that. If not, and I was doing this from scratch I would just write a function that does this (hardcode a calendar, january has 31 days, february 28 days, etc). Pay attention to leap years if relevant.

Once you get the number of days in the total time range, divide that number by the number of chunks. Now you have how many days should be in each chunk. Then build your intervals by starting at the first date and adding to it the number representing "days in each chunk". Sometimes an interval will begin in one month and end in a future month, this is where you will need to use a library or the hardcoded reference for how many days in each month.

Hope this helps.

Edit: see my comment below for links to functions that will help.

Edit2: This answer doesn't really help much now seeing how the question was edited after I made this response. But the functions linked in my comment can still be useful.

Comment: I just saw your P.S. edit. [Here is a post explaining how to get days between two dates in Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time) On the bottom of the [quick-start guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) you can find examples on how to add days to a certain date.