# How to include start date in Joda Time daysBetween?

Tags: java, date, jodatime, android-jodatime

Upon testing JODA time to get number of days that has been selected, it is excluding the start day.

```
    Date from = day1.getTime();
    Date to = day2.getTime();

    int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(from), new DateTime(to)).getDays();
```

So if I select, December 14 - 16, it is only showing "2" as result instead of 3.

Is it safe to just "+1" the result or is there a right way to do this in JODA time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Days.daysBetween(-,-) method just subtracts the start day from the end day. If you want to get the total no of days including the start day then you must have to minus 1 from the start date.

Comment: Or more simply, add one to the result.

Comment: yes u can also add 1 to the result .

Comment: thanks guys. It worked! :) the toLocalDate or withTimeAtStartOfDay for some reason doesn't produce the result I expected.