# JodaTime - Test about dates fails randomly

Tags: jodatime

I have this code:

```
public static int getDaysBetween(Date dateA, Date dateB) {
    return Days.daysBetween(
        new DateTime(dateA), 
        new DateTime(dateB))
    .getDays();
}
```

And this test case:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Date dateFrom = buildDate(10, Calendar.JANUARY, 2018);
    Date dateTo = buildDate(1, Calendar.JANUARY, 2018);
    assertEquals(DateUtils.getDaysBetween(dateFrom, dateTo), -9);
}
```

Test passes most of the times, but it fails randomly. Sometimes, `getDaysBetween` returns `-8` instead of `-9`.

What's wrong? Is it any JodaTime bug?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't technically a bug, just an annoyance. Turns out of the difference between your 2 days doesn't reach a day, it returns 0. And if you've 1.99999 days, it returns 1.

Theres a post for a very similar issue that could help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time)