# Can one parse ( into a method, not from scanner) a varaible of type DateTime into a method at call time?

Tags: java, datetime

```
Datetime start;
DateTime stop;  

public void datesIbtween(DateTime start, DateTime stop) {
         //compare start and stop, the calculate diffrence
         }
```

I do not want to parse the start and stop as String, I was wondering if is a there a way I can parse in Datetime variable into a method? if not? what are my alternatives?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "is a there a way I can parse in Datetime variable into a method." Could you clarify that a bit?

Comment: What do you mean by parse into a method?

Comment: I wanted the method to calculate the number of day between 2 dates (start and stop). The start and stop variables are of type "Datetime" and I expect their values to be parsed when that method is called. The question is - is it doable?

Comment: @Martin'sRun I wanted to say " the caller will supply the values of those DateTime variables when they use an object to call it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can just use the `time` library:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
public class DaysInBetween {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate before = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MAY, 24);
    LocalDate after = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JULY, 29);
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(before, after);
    System.out.println(daysBetween);
   }    
}
```

### NOTE

This means you can parse the date input from the caller as a `LocalDate` (i.e: days=`int`, months=`string`, and year=`int`) then pass it to the imported function to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely can use DateTime as your method parameter, if that's what you meant. To find the difference between your DateTimes use the [Date.daysBetween](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-) method.

Check : [Number of days between two dates in Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time)